# How to test if a prop is rendered correctly in a Component using Jest and Enzyme in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, tdd, enzyme

I have a React component named **Product** which looks like this:

```
<div>
            <Wrapper>
                <Heading>{props.headerText}</Heading>
                <Service>({props.items.length})</Service>
            </Wrapper>
            {props.items !== undefined && props.items.length > 0 ? (
                <TableWrapper>
                    {props.items &&
                        props.items.length > 0 && (
                            <DataTable paginationSize={props.paginationSize}>
                                <DataTable.Heading accessor="name"> Name </DataTable.Heading>
                                <DataTable.Heading accessor="id"> Service ID </DataTable.Heading>
                                <DataTable.Heading accessor="type"> Access </DataTable.Heading>
                                <DataTable.Heading accessor="band"> Band </DataTable.Heading>
                                <DataTable.Heading accessor="noUsers"> Users </DataTable.Heading>

                                {props.tableItems.map((p, i) => {
                                    return <DataTable.Row key={i} data={p} />;
                                })}
                            </DataTable>
                        )}
                </TableWrapper>
            ) : (
                <NoMessage>{props.noItemMessage}</NoMessage>
            )}
        </div>
```

where **Wrapper**, **Heading**, **Service**, **TableWrapper** are styled-components. I am trying **to test this component using Jest and Enzyme to check if the headerText prop is being rendered correctly**.The below given code is how I am trying to write my test case:

```
 test("header text is being passed through correctly", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
            <Product items={data} headerText="Service" paginationSize="5" noItemMessage="No results found" />
        );
        expect(wrapper.find(HeaderText).text()).toEqual("Service");
```

but I get this error as:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'blue' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.RightArrow.Icons.RightArrow.extend.props (src/lib/DataTable.js:149:129)
```

and the line 149 in DataTable.js is:

```
color: ${props => props.theme.secondary.blue};
```

I am not able to figure out why I am getting this error. Can anyone please guide me with this issue? I am just trying to check if the headerText is rendered properly from the props.

Answer (score 1):

to get ride of add theme as props in your wrapper

`<Product items={data} theme={{secondary: {blue: ''}}} headerText="Service" paginationSize="5" noItemMessage="No results found" />`

or mock it

`import { createSpy } from 'expect';
const theme = createSpy();
<Product items={data} theme={theme} headerText="Service" paginationSize="5" noItemMessage="No results found" />`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the first option, but its still giving the same error.

Comment: and if you try:

theme={{secondary: {blue: () => {} }}}

Comment: then you should try declaring color as a props in your wrapper. If it's still doesn't work let me know

Comment: I tried this code `test("header text is being passed through correctly", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
            <ProductTable
                tableItems={data}
                theme={{ secondary: { blue: () => {} } }}
                headerText="Service"
                paginationSize="5"
                noItemMessage="No results found"
                color={{ blue: "#0096e6" }}
            />
        );
        expect(wrapper.find(Heading).text()).toEqual("Service");` but still getting the same error.is it the correct way?

Comment: yes that's the idea to get ride of this error. and if you try 
```theme={{ secondary: { blue: "#0096e6" } }} ```

or even 
```color={{ theme: {secondary: { blue: "#0096e6" }} }}```

Comment: can you copy/past all the object of ```color: ${props => props.theme.secondary.blue};```

Comment: `export const RightArrow = Icons.RightArrow.extend
    color: ${props => props.theme.darkGray};
    margin: 0 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover {
        color: ${props => props.theme.secondary.blue};
    } `

Comment: Actually RightArrow is a styled-component which is using the style from RightArrow Icon

Comment: did you try to mock it as explained above, if you don't want to use expect lib you can use jest to mock it ```const theme = jest.fn()```

Answer (score 0):

we can use the themeProvider of styled-componnets to create a wrapper around the `shallow` or `mount` methods of enzyme, like below:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

const mountWithTheme = (children, theme={}, options = {}) => {
 const wrapper = mount(<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>, options);
 return wrapper.mount({});
};

test("header text is being passed through correctly", () => {
  const wrapper =  mountWithTheme(<Product items={data} headerText="Service" paginationSize="5" noItemMessage="No results found" />,
{ secondary: { blue: 'blue' } }); 
// we passed the theme we want as an argument to the mountWithTheme method
  expect(wrapper.find(HeaderText).text()).toEqual("Service");
});
```

It will be better to pull out the utils mountWithTheme and ShallowWithTheme to a different file so that it can be reused, and also as a suggestion, you can create a mockTheme file which contains some default themes which can be passed to these wrappers instead of manually passing the theme each time we are consuming these utils.

More more information, visit below link:
https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1319